# Is there a client side tool like Xenu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want a tool like [Xenu's Link Sleuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenu's_Link_Sleuth) developed using JavaScript because I cannot use any sever side scripting. 
Alternatively, can you offer any tips and links to help to develop a client side tool.

Comment: What's Xenu? Please ask a more specific question regarding a *programming problem*, this is way too vague.

Comment: xenu is a link checker it list all the links in given url and other properties

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX requests to check links on your own domain, but because of the same origin policy, you can't use it to check other websites.